# html select tag bug causes reflow during css transform animation. Ideas for workarounds?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms, html-select

Apparently including a select element as part of a css transform animation causes reflows to occur and negatively affects the animation's perceived smoothness and render time. Now in desktop browsers this is not really important and hardly noticeable, but on mobile devices unnecessary reflows are very expensive!

Here is a basic fiddle that demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/w6NUT/
Open up the Dev Tools Timeline and notice how setting the select element to `display: none;` causes the "Layout" records to stop.

I have a rather complex web app where I'm creating a flip animation of a node with many child elements and this 'select' element is the only problem child.

Any ideas for how I might be able to work around this? I may end up submitting this as a bug to the webkit folks but I'm also looking for a short-term kludge hack fix.

Comment: Did you get a chance to analyze the jsfiddle I created? Animating CSS Transforms are not suppose to cause reflows, but for some reason having a descendant select tag _does_. Take the select element away, and reflows do not occur during the animation. AFAIK, this is an undocumented bug.

Comment: I ended up submitting a bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94407